# how to select the first child of the first siblings of a li?

Tags: css, siblings

i would like to select out the nested li from my css selector

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z28na6m8/)

```css
li:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>to be selected</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>not to be selected</li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever the parent of the first `ul` is use that and then `>` (this means  immediate children, learn more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)). Like so.

```css
body > ul > li:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>to be selected</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>not to be selected</li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this might be a obvious question, but why does `body > ul > li:first-child` work but `ul > li:first-child` doesn't? `body` seems like a redundant selector, unless it only required for the jsfiddle env

Comment: @atmd It means immediate children.

Comment: @Ruddy no I get the meaning of the selector, but in the real world it's unlikely to have a `ul` as an immediate child of the `body`. I guess without a real world example of the OP's problem it's still the right answer

Comment: @atmd Oh, yes this is just in my case the parent of `ul` is body. For the OP (as i stated in the question) they will need to put whatever the parent of there `ul` is there instead of `body`.

Comment: why is ul > li:first-child not sufficient?

Comment: @Matoeil because `ul` has children `ul`, so the CSS will apply to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the styles, and then undo them.

```
li:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
}

li li:first-child {
    background-color: inherit;
    list-style-type: inherit;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
}
```

Fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/wLspzcho/

Comment: I remember for IE6 we had to do it this way, since [child combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) were introduced later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you wanted but try this

```css
.first > li:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
    <li>to be selected</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>not to be selected</li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        
</ul>
```